# Description for Stack Overflow Teams page on Google

Tags: bug, old-teams, google, description

When searching "Stack Overflow teams" on Google, here is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Conveniently, the description points to [my own team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/290/barlow-programming). <sub>(Yay, we're popular!)</sub>

It's been like this for a while, and although I don't object to such a promotional description, shouldn't it be something more relevant to the overall concept of teams? For example, if you look at the link under it, "The Power of Teams" (I'll copy it below if you can't see the image):

> **The Power of Teams** This past spring, the product team held a multi-week brainstorming...

... which I assume leads to a description of Stack Overflow Teams. Or something like the concise description when you search "Stack Overflow" on Google:

> A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

This isn't really a major problem, but I am wondering if this is intended behavior (and if so, how does it choose the team? Perhaps longest description on the first page of "Recent"?), and whether or not it should be changed to something more relevant.

I know Teams is still a beta feature, and this is probably an unnoticed little bug; but great job with it so far!

Comment: This is something Google decides, not SO. If a bug, it's their bug.

Comment: I'm think there's @Meta data they can include in the page to *influence* what Google shows to some extent.

Comment: @JeremyBanks That's what I was thinking-- isn't there a `<meta name="description">` tag?

Comment: "Google's generation of page titles and descriptions (or "snippets") is completely automated and takes into account both the content of a page as well as references to it that appear on the web. The goal of the snippet and title is to best represent and describe each result and explain how it relates to the user's query." Source [Review your page titles and snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en)